# QSettings does not differentiate between string and int values

Tags: c++, qt, types, qsettings

I am writing and reading string and int values using a file-backed `QSettings` object.
When I later try to read the values from a different process, the values are read as strings instead of int.

This is the code I am using to write values:

```
QSettings settings("TestQSettings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
settings.setValue("AAA",QString("111"));
settings.setValue("BBB",222);
```

This is the file created:

```
[General]
AAA=111
BBB=222
```

This is the code I am using to read values:

```
QVariant qvar = settings.value("AAA");
std::cout << "AAA type " << qvar.type() << std::endl;
qvar = settings.value("BBB");
std::cout << "BBB type " << qvar.type() << std::endl;
```

If I run this code from the same process:

```
AAA type 10
BBB type 2
```

If I run this code from a different process:

```
AAA type 10
BBB type 10
```

I know it's possible to convert the types after they have been read.
Unfortunately, this solution will require modifying Windows legacy cross-platform code which I prefer not to modify, for example multiple calls to `RegQueryValueEx()`.

Is it possible to store and read the type information for strings and integers?

For example, Strings will have quotes `""` and integers will not:

```
[General]
AAA="111"
BBB=222
```

This problem is present on both Qt 4 and Qt 5, on Linux.

Comment: I couldn't find an actual question in your post. And I am afraid `.ini` files don't store type information, so if the question is "how do I make the `.ini` file keep the type," I am afraid the answer is "you don't."

Comment: your program should be knowing of what type it has to expect of its ini file. so if you store a int there, convert the QVariant to an integer and if it fails, throw exception ... simple as that

Comment: Updated the question. It's not that simple to modify the code, since I'm doing a wrapper for Windows registry calls from another project. Too many calls, and I don't want to modify that code too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was very simple.

When values are written to the INI file, the type is known.
I am appending to the value "\"STRING right before SetValue

When values are read back from the INI file.
I verify that string types have the above postfix.
If they do, I chop the postfix off.
If they don't I assume they are integers instead of strings.

Works like a charm!

Thanks to you all and especially @Kuba Ober for practically handing out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Whoa whoa, are you using .ini files or the registry?

With .ini files it's obviously impossible to know what the type was, since it's all a string. You can attempt conversion of the variant to an integer (*don't use `canConvert`*!), and assume it's an integer if it converts into one.

With the registry, `QSettings` will work as you expect it to.

I really don't see what the problem is. Don't use `.ini` files if you wish to retain type information. You'd face exactly the same problems if you wrote the code by hand in a platform-dependent manner.

You can explicitly write quoted strings into the `.ini` files, and check for presence of quotes when reading them back. If the quotes are not present, you can try conversion to an integer.

Comment: I'm using ini files on Linux.

Comment: I'm using ini files on Linux. But the code I'm compiling with is shared with a Windows project and should compile for both platforms. I am looking into QStringList with the size of 1. This looks promising.

Comment: If I add quotes on both sides of the string, the string is stored without the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem for a component which needs to save and restore variants of arbitrary type, without knowing what its clients expect.  The solution was to store the variant's `typeName()` alongside each value:

```
void store(QSettings& settings, const QString& key, const QVariant& value)
{
    settings.setValue(key+"value", value);
    settings.setValue(key+"type", value.typeName());
}
```

When reading back, we also read the type name, and `convert()` the variant if it's not already the correct type, before returning it.

```
QVariant retrieve(const QSettings& settings, const QString& key)
{
    auto value = settings.value(key+"value");
    const auto typeName = settings.value(key+"type").toString();

    const bool wasNull = value.isNull();                         // NOTE 1
    const auto t = QMetaType::type(typeName.toUtf8());           // NOTE 2

    if (value.userType() != t && !value.convert(t) && !wasNull) {
        // restore value that was cleared by the failed convert()
        value = settings.value(key+"value");
        qWarning() << "Failed to convert value" << value << "to" << typeName;
    }

    return value;
}
```

---

#### Notes

1. The `wasNull` variable is in there because of this niggle of `convert()`:

   > **Warning:** For historical reasons, converting a null `QVariant` results in a null value of the desired type (e.g., an empty string for `QString`) and a result of `false`.

   In this case, we need to ignore the misleading return value, and keep the successfully-converted null variant of the correct type.

---

2. It's not clear that UTF-8 is the correct encoding for `QMetaType` names (perhaps local 8-bit is assumed?); my types are all ASCII, so I just use `toLatin1()` instead, which might be faster.  If it were an issue, I'd use `QString::fromLatin1` in the `store()` method (instead of implicit `char*` to `QString` conversion), to ensure a clean round-trip.

   If the type name is not found, `t` will be `QMetaType::UnknownType`; that's okay, because `convert()` will then fail, and we'll return the unconverted variant (or a null).  It's not great, but it's a corner case that won't happen in normal usage, and my system will recover reasonably quickly.