# QSettings with different types

Tags: qt, qsettings

I'm trying to store some parameters with different type using QSettings (ini file, Linux).
When I'm reading values from this using `settings.value()` I just get QStrings.
Are there any way to store type of QVariant inside this settings file or should I use other storage instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qsettings does not differentiate between string and int values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355112/qsettings-does-not-differentiate-between-string-and-int-values)

Comment: How are you using settings, if you do not know beforehand which types they have? If, for example, you store window size, you know that it should be QSize, and cast accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#value), the `QSettings::value()` function returns a `QVariant`.  This should then be converted to whatever type you want.

You can use `QVariant::type()` to find the type you stored in the QSettings.

This is how QSettings should work, and does, using the NativeFormat on Windows.

However, when using an ini file and for most simple types - including strings and integers - QSettings uses the same simple representation in the ini file and therefore merges these types.  They all come back as QString type in the QVariant.

More complex types **are** properly encoded in the ini file and so these types are preserved.

Comment: I need to know what type I should convert this QVariant into. Is it possible to get this information from QSettings?

Comment: You can call `type` on the `QVariant`.

Comment: QVariant::type() returns QString instead for int, bool and string.

Comment: @N1ghtLight Oh yes Eckler is right - the ini file format does not correctly preserve simple types.  Works for more complex types though.  I've added some more detail to the post.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [QSettings does not differentiate between string and int values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355112/qsettings-does-not-differentiate-between-string-and-int-values)

> Every value of QVariant which is read from a .ini file by QSettings has string type.

There is also proposed solution to manually append type information to stored strings. So, if during reading the special postfix is not found it is possible to manually decide regarding conversion to int or to bool.

By the way, for more complex types (like `QSize`) the type information is stored, so `QVariat` type is correct.